# shell script for getting csv with curl

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, curl

I think this question is very simple, but I just started using shell scripts.

I have this so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

new_url=$(python get_url.py)
echo $new_url
curl -o mycsv_file.csv $new_url
```

And it is not working (not creating the `mycsv_file.csv` file on current directory). I get a `new_url` with a python script, it is working because when I do `echo` it prints the url I want.

Normally If I do:

```
curl -o mycsv_file.csv "exampleurl.com/file_example.csv"
```

from console, it works great, it creates the `mycsv_file.csv` on the current directory, but I don't know what is the problem with the shell script. Maybe it is some kind of problem with the `""` on the url for curl, but I also tried appending the `""` to the `new_url` variable and it is the same.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Try `curl -o mycsv_file.csv $(python get_url.py)`

Comment: not working, it works the same.

Comment: It doesn't show errors, shows like curl is working, but it spends 0:00:01 of time and after that it finishes, but the file isn't created.

Comment: Try with `#!/bin/bash -vx`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the python script was adding a newline to the end of the string, so curl was checking a different URL (with newline at the end).

Comment: `curl -o mycsv_file.csv $new_url` -> Having no quotes around `$new_url` should strip out any newline at the end. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
curl -o mycsv_file.csv "$new_url"
```

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work. It shows that curl tries to connect somewhere but doesn't creates the `mycsv_file.csv` file

Comment: Try without the -o so curl prints to std out - just to make sure it's actually getting data from the server.

Comment: It shows nothing, I think the problem is the `""`, but how should be the right way to change the `new_url` variable